# Show text bold which before link and when click navigate to link in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have below string which contains link check below image :-

**Note:- Below string is not static. I get it from firebase collection.It just for example**

[image]

Check in last i need to show **Share a win, give feedback or ask a question!** to bold in app and when click on this text need to navigate to **help@easybitesapp.com** which have in last of string.

Its working fine in **SwiftUI IOS using NSAttributedString** check below image :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Use This Package To Launch Url:**

[url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

```
final Uri _url = Uri.parse('help@easybitesapp.com');

void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: Material(
          child: Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: _launchUrl,
              child: Text('Share a win, give feedback or ask a question', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 18.0)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

void _launchUrl() async {
  if (!await launchUrl(_url)) throw 'Could not launch $_url';
}
```

Comment: Hi @Emon Hossain Munna
Thanks for answer but its not solution string are get from firebase collection so i not set static link.

Comment: @RaviLimbani its okay then, use the url dynamically from your firebase response